# Solspace User forgot_password return link broken

Tags: solspace-user, forgot-password

**EE 2.11.5**

**User 3.5.3**

Everything about my Reset Password chain of templates works, except for the return link in the forgot_password form.

```
{exp:user:forgot_password
    secure_action="yes"
    secure_return="yes"
    secure_reset_link="yes"
    return="members/forgot-sent"
    password_reset_template="members/reset-password/%id%"
    password_reset_email_subject="Password Reset Request"
    password_reset_email_template="members/_password_reset_email_template"
}
```

After the form is submitted, instead of getting redirected to:
**https://domain.com/members/forgot-sent**, I get redirected to: **https://domain.com/https://domain.com/members/forgot-sent**

Which brings me to a blank page with just the following error: *The URI you submitted is not allowed.*

I've tried adding a beginning slash and putting in the full URL in the return parameter, but no matter what, that return parameter is not working.

I go back to the email that was sent, click on the link to the reset page, and using the create new password form, everything works fine. I even have on my reset form a return parameter that DOES work fine.

```
{exp:user:reset_password
    reset_code="{segment_3}"
    return="members/login/success"
}
```

So only the return parameter on my forgot_password template code is not working properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it's this parameter that's causing the issue.

```
secure_return="yes"
```

If I remove that from the forgot_password form, then the form works and the return template I put in works properly.